# Image height will only be retrieved once out of a big array of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

So like i wrote in the title, i have multiple elements with same class i fetch that class and try to check for the child image's width/height/src of that image.

i only manage to get the height // width of the first image however i get the src of all images.

here is the html:

```
<a class="test">
<img src="http://www.kitchenspro.com/files/Testimonials/Large/1502046700250312a71707.jpg">
</a>
<a class="test">
<img src="http://www.kitchenspro.com/files/Testimonials/Large/40183.9461166782.jpg">
</a>
<a class="test">
<img src="http://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s480x480/391362_365319466870994_1543740404_n.jpg">
</a>
```

here is the jquery

```
var imagesrc= "";
var imageheight = "";
var imagewidth = "";
var i=0;
$(".test > img").each(function() {
i++;
imagesrc = $(this).attr("src");
imageheight = $(this).width();
imagewidth = $(this).height();
document.write("<br>This is image's src: " + imagesrc + " This is img height: " + imageheight + " this is width: " + imagewidth + "<br>");            
});
```

I apologize if i didnt present the code the right way.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.write` as it can have unexpected behavior. I just tested your code as it is, but with `console.log` instead of `document.write` and got all the correct information for all images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what @Musa said.

To help clean up your code and give a lesson on efficiency and native javascript, I have supplied a snippet.

```
// Document Fragments are lightweight DOM containers. Append elements to this in loops and then attach the fragment to the actual DOM afterwards to increase efficiency. 
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// i, or index, comes out of box in most loops.
$(".test img").each(function(i, el) {
 // Local variables specific to each image
 var imagesrc = $(this).attr("src");
 var imageheight = $(this).width();
 var imagewidth = $(this).height();
 var message = "This is image's src: " + imagesrc + " This is img height: " + imageheight + " this is width: " + imagewidth;

 // Appending the node to the frag with native js
 var p = document.createElement("p");
 p.innerText = message;
 frag.appendChild(p);

 // Viewing the console message for fun
 console.log(message);     
});

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. grandecomplex i will select your as then answer.

Comment: You can easily replace the fragment as an array. Such as var widths = []. Then in the loop, widths.push(width);

Answer (score 2):

The first call to `document.write` destroys the rest of elements so that's why you only get information from one of them, use .append() or something else to show your results.

Comment: So you both are positing its       document.write? which does the problem ? i mean i dont really want to present the detalis yet i just want to put them in an array. i will continue testing will see in a sec